# Probability of a group being chosen

Tags: probability

In a very small village in King Arthur’s England, there are 9 women, who each own 4 shrubberies,
and 12 men, who each own 9 shrubberies. King Arthur picks 4 peasants at random (without replacing).
 a) Let X = the number of women selected. Write down the explicit probability function of X
(probability of each x to 3 decimal places)?
 b) Let Y = the total number of shrubberies. Write down the pmf of Y (probability of each possible
number of shrubberies).
 c) Find the expected value and variance of both X and Y
I'm really not sure how to get started on this other than the probability that a woman that is picked is 43% and a man is 57%.

Comment: Are you familiar with Hypergeometric distribution?

Comment: Use the fact that the probability of choosing $m$ men and $4-m$ women is $$\frac{{12\choose m}\cdot{9\choose {4-m}}}{{21\choose 4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

As Alex already wrote, we have $$P(X=k) = {{9\choose k}{12\choose 4-k}\over {21\choose 4}}$$

and for [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Probability_mass_function) we have $$E(X)= 4\cdot {9\over 21}=1,714$$ $$Var(X)=4\cdot {9\cdot 12\over 21^2} {17\over 20}={12\cdot 17\over 49\cdot 5}=0,833$$

Further we have $Y= 4X+9(4-X) =36-5X$ so, for $l\in\{1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36\}$ $$f_Y(l)=P(Y=l) = P(X={36-l\over 5}) =...$$

and $$E(Y)= 36-4\cdot E(X) = {240\over 7}= 34,286$$ $$Var(Y)=Var(-5X)= 25\cdot  {12\cdot 17\over 49\cdot 5} = 20,816$$